# Parsing double grouped number with readr::parse_double()

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

Code shows as:

```
readr::parse_double("123,456,789.987", 
                    locale = locale(decimal_mark = ".", 
                                    grouping_mark = ","))
```

where the expected result is: 123456789.987
But it turns out this throws an error:

```
1 parsing failure.
row # A tibble: 1 x 4 col     row   col               expected       actual 
expected   <int> <int>                  <chr>        <chr> actual 1     1    
NA no trailing characters ,456,789.987
[1] NA
attr(,"problems")
```

I was wondering why this happened and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it looks like you need `parse_number`: from `?parse_number`

> The grouping mark specified by the locale is ignored inside the number.

The help page for `parse_double()` doesn't say it *doesn't* ignore the grouping mark, but it doesn't say it does ...

```
print(parse_number("123,456,789.987"),digits=20)
## [1] 123456789.98700000346
```

(The extra digits at the end occur because this number can't be exactly represented in double-precision floating point)